# How to fix ' "Missing URI template variable 'uuid' for method parameter of type UUID"'?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have updated the pathvariable from String to UUID in the controller of a spring-boot implemented web application. I am using swagger for the front end. I am getting "Missing URI template variable 'uuid' for method parameter of type UUID" exception in the response after the change.

I have updated the pathvariable from String to UUID in the controller of a spring-boot implemented web application. I am using swagger for the front end. At the db side I am using mongodb. I am converting this uuid to string to use the exiting find method implemented for mongodb. I am getting this exception in the response. The same thing is working in another project, Couldn't find out why it is not working here.

```
@Path("/uuid")
@RequestMapping(value = "/uuid", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ApiOperation(value = "Retrieves result based on Unique Identifier", notes = "Returns result matching with the Unique Identifier", 
    position = 1, response = Response.class, httpMethod = "GET")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message = "Invalid request."),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, message = "Record not found."),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, message = "Not authorized for this operation."),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT, message = "Object state out-of-date."),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message = "Server error") })
ResponseEntity<Response> getResultByUuid(@ApiParam(required = true, name = "uuid", value = "uuid") @PathParam("uuid") @PathVariable("uuid") UUID uuid,
        @ApiParam(access = "hidden") HttpServletRequest request)
        throws IOException;
```

1. It should be fetching me the result instead. Now it throws the exception. It doesn't even reach the controller, suspecting some spring configuration dependency stuff. Not sure what is that?

Answer (score 2):

Path variable must be mentioned in the request mapping in curly brackets.
In your code the following line

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uuid", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
```

can be changed to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{uuid}", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
```

to fix that error.

Comment: With these changes I ended up with  "Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path" exception. Then I figured out that parent class has the same path, so making @RequestMapping(value = "uuid/{uuid}", method = { RequestMethod.GET }) solved the issue for me. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Request mapping to `/.../uuid` for parent looks unusual to me. If your naming convention for API paths is based on semantics of the model, this would mean that you expose single UUID as resource and subpaths would map to properties of that UUID - your code example does not look like that. If this was not your intention, I would recommend you to change the mapping for parent and keep `/{uuid}` for child. Example: `/api/v1/users` for collection of all users (parent) and `/api/v1/users/{uuid}` for specific user (child).

Comment: since parent class is from a framework, internal to the project we can't actually modify it. And _@RequestMapping_ has to be unique in the class and parent class combination, so I just modified the request mapping of my class(child class) and it worked